# Should flink job manager crash during zookeeper upgrade?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying to understand if behaviour of the flink jobmanager during zookeeper upgrade is expected or not.

I'm running flink 1.11.2 in kubernetes, with zookeeper server 3.5.4-beta.
While I'm doing zookeeper upgrade, there is a 20 seconds zookeeper downtime. I'd expect to either flink job to restart or few warnings in the logs during those 20 seconds. Instead, I see whole flink JVM crash ( and later the pod restart).

I expected for flink to internally retry zookeeper requests, so I'm surprised it crashes. Is this expected, or is it a bug?

From the logs

```
org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:68) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:366) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
[09-Feb-2021 11:30:00.197 UTC] INFO org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn [] - Opening socket connection to server zdzk.servicexxx/192.168.190.92:2181
[09-Feb-2021 11:30:00.197 UTC] INFO org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn [] - Socket connection established to zdzk.servicexxx/192.168.190.92:2181, initiating session
[09-Feb-2021 11:30:00.198 UTC] WARN org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn [] - Session 0x3012b0057140004 for server zdzk.servicexxx/192.168.190.92:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:68) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:366) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
[09-Feb-2021 11:30:02.294 UTC] INFO org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn [] - Opening socket connection to server zdzk.servicexxx/192.168.190.92:2181
[09-Feb-2021 11:30:02.295 UTC] INFO org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn [] - Socket connection established to zdzk.servicexxx/192.168.190.92:2181, initiating session
[09-Feb-2021 11:30:02.295 UTC] WARN org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn [] - Session 0x3012b0057140004 for server zdzk.servicexxx/192.168.190.92:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:68) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:366) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
[09-Feb-2021 11:30:03.841 UTC] INFO org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn [] - Opening socket connection to server zdzk.servicexxx/192.168.190.92:2181
[09-Feb-2021 11:30:03.842 UTC] INFO org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn [] - Socket connection established to zdzk.servicexxx/192.168.190.92:2181, initiating session
[09-Feb-2021 11:30:03.842 UTC] WARN org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn [] - Session 0x3012b0057140004 for server zdzk.servicexxx/192.168.190.92:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:68) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:366) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
[09-Feb-2021 11:30:04.175 UTC] ERROR org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl [] - Background operation retry gave up
org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:862) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:990) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:943) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:66) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:346) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_192]
[09-Feb-2021 11:30:04.176 UTC] ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.retriever.impl.RpcGatewayRetriever [] - Received error from LeaderRetrievalService.
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Unhandled error in ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService:Background operation retry gave up
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderretrieval.ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService.unhandledError(ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService.java:208) [flink-dist_2.11-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$6.apply(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:713) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$6.apply(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:709) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:100) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:92) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.logError(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:708) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:874) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:990) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:943) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:66) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:346) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_192]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:862) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    ... 10 more
[09-Feb-2021 11:30:04.178 UTC] ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobManagerRunnerImpl      [] - Leader Election Service encountered a fatal error.
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Unhandled error in ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService: Background operation retry gave up
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderelection.ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService.unhandledError(ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService.java:430) [flink-dist_2.11-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$6.apply(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:713) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$6.apply(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:709) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:100) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:92) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.logError(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:708) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:874) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:990) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:943) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:66) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:346) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_192]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:862) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    ... 10 more
[09-Feb-2021 11:30:04.179 UTC] ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.retriever.impl.RpcGatewayRetriever [] - Received error from LeaderRetrievalService.
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Unhandled error in ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService:Background operation retry gave up
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderretrieval.ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService.unhandledError(ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService.java:208) [flink-dist_2.11-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$6.apply(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:713) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$6.apply(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:709) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:100) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:92) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.logError(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:708) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:874) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:990) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:943) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:66) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:346) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_192]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:862) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    ... 10 more
[09-Feb-2021 11:30:04.180 UTC] ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Fatal error occurred in ResourceManager.
org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.exceptions.ResourceManagerException: Received an error from the LeaderElectionService.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.handleError(ResourceManager.java:1053) [flink-dist_2.11-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderelection.ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService.unhandledError(ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService.java:430) [flink-dist_2.11-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$6.apply(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:713) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$6.apply(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:709) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:100) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:92) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.logError(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:708) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:874) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:990) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:943) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:66) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:346) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_192]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Unhandled error in ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService: Background operation retry gave up
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:862) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    ... 10 more
[09-Feb-2021 11:30:04.181 UTC] ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - Fatal error occurred in the cluster entrypoint.
org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.exceptions.ResourceManagerException: Received an error from the LeaderElectionService.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.handleError(ResourceManager.java:1053) [flink-dist_2.11-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderelection.ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService.unhandledError(ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService.java:430) [flink-dist_2.11-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$6.apply(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:713) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$6.apply(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:709) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:100) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:92) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.logError(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:708) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:874) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:990) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:943) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:66) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:346) [flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_192]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Unhandled error in ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService: Background operation retry gave up
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper3.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator4.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:862) ~[flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14-11.0]
    ... 10 more
[09-Feb-2021 11:30:04.196 UTC] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer                     [] - Stopped BLOB server at 0.0.0.0:6124
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the answer from the flink community
http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Should-flink-job-manager-crash-during-zookeeper-upgrade-tt41393.html

What I need to tweak is the following 2 params, and make sure that flink waits for longer than the period it takes for zookeeper to find new leader

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/deployment/config.html#high-availability-zookeeper-client-max-retry-attempts
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/deployment/config.html#high-availability-zookeeper-client-retry-wait

Answer (score 0):

If a zookeeper quorum is maintained during the upgrade, then the Flink job manager should not be impacted. Otherwise it's not surprising that the job manager would fail.

Normally you would upgrade the zookeeper followers first, one by one, and then upgrade the leader last. Verify that the quorum has been reestablished before taking down another node.

Comment: zookeeper quorum wasn't maintained during leader upgrade, and default jobmanager zookeeper retries weren't long enough. So, the solution was to increase them ( I hadn't known originally that retry can be tweaked in flink.conf )